# Cannot retrive values from RecyclerView ,Recyclerview is populated via the SQlite DB

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Basically we need to get the email from the `recyclerview`

We tried adding `onClickListener` on the `TextView` in the `RecyclerView`, but when there are more than one entries in the `RecyclerView`, we cannot get the value.

Is there any way that I can store the values in variables before populating the `RecyclerView` and passing the values to another Activity?

I tried getting the values from the `TextView` in the `RecyclerView`, but I always show the text on the first row

Intent doesn't work on the Adapter class because its not an activity

```
ArrayList<ModelClass> objModelClassArrayList;

public DatabaseRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<ModelClass> objModelClassArrayList) {
    this.objModelClassArrayList = objModelClassArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DatabaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View singleRow= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
    return new DatabaseViewHolder(singleRow);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DatabaseViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    ModelClass objModelClass=objModelClassArrayList.get(position);
    holder.userNameTV.setText(objModelClass.getName());
    holder.userLocation.setText(objModelClass.getAddress());
    String e1=objModelClass.getEmail();
    holder.userEmail.setText(e1);


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return objModelClassArrayList.size();
}

public static class DatabaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    TextView userNameTV,userLocation,userEmail;
    public DatabaseViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        userNameTV=itemView.findViewById(R.id.sr_userNameTV);
        userLocation=itemView.findViewById(R.id.sr_location);
        userEmail=itemView.findViewById(R.id.sr_email);
    }
}
```

I want to extract the email from a single row and pass it to another page where I can pass it in the DB query to get the results from the database.

Comment: Your question is too confusing. What you want take email from TextView and pass it another activity?

Comment: "*is there anyway that i can store the values in variables before populating the RecyclerView and passing the values to another Activity*" yes, you just need to create a new reference to the Model Type. e.g. in this case it could be `ArrayList<ModelClass> objModelClassArrayList` as you can see you already have that reference to data available, so get email from `objModelClassArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, need to pass context in the constructor of the adapter which can help you to open another activity from the recyclerView adapter. Then Inside BindViewHolder, you can create clickListener like as below,

```
         holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     String emailText=holder.userEmail.getText().trim();
                     Intent intent=new Intent(context,activity_name_you _want_ to_open);
                     intent.setExtra("emailName",emailText);
                     (name of activity contains RV)context.startActivity(intent)
                     //Note: here context needs to be typecasted to activity from which we want to open new activity.

                    }
                });
```